# How to change the size of column title on factorplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The code below only seems to change the size of x and y axis labels on the factorplot, but I can't figure out how to change the size of each column title/label on the graphs.

```
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
sns.set_context(font_scale =20)
g = sns.factorplot(x='Fare_bins',  col = 'Cabin', kind ='count', data=    Fare_Cabin, col_wrap =3,
       size=3, aspect =1.3 , palette="muted")


# labeling the x and y labels and changing the font size for most of the labels
g.set_ylabels("Instances")
g.set_xlabels('Fare')
g.axes[0].xaxis.label.set(size=14)
g.axes[0].yaxis.label.set(size=14)
g.axes[1].xaxis.label.set(size=14)
g.axes[2].xaxis.label.set(size=14)
g.axes[3].xaxis.label.set(size=14)
g.axes[4].yaxis.label.set(size=14)
g.axes[4].xaxis.label.set(size=14)
g.axes[5].xaxis.label.set(size=14)
g.axes[6].xaxis.label.set(size=14)
g.axes[7].yaxis.label.set(size=14)
g.axes[7].xaxis.label.set(size=14)
```

However this only changes the size for x and y labels and not the column header which in this case is represented by the values of "cabin"

(Sorry, I'm not quite sure how to post the graph inside the OP)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `set_titles` method of the the `FacetGrid`.

Default title size:

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
g = sns.factorplot(x='sex',  col='size', kind ='count', data=tips, col_wrap=3)
```

[image]

Bigger titles:

```
g = sns.factorplot(x='sex',  col='size', kind ='count', data=tips, col_wrap=3)
g.set_titles(size=20)
```

[image]